# Programmatic POST to Selenium Browser

Tags: post, selenium

I have Selenium working fine to do a bunch of interactive things, however I reach a point where it would be much better if I could programmatically POST to a form on the page that the Selenium browser is currently sitting on (vs. a bunch of sendkeys and a submit click).  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The WebElement has [submit](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#submit%28%29)

> void submit()
>
> If this current element is a form, or an element within a form, then
>   this will be submitted to the remote server. If this causes the
>   current page to change, then this method will block until the new page
>   is loaded.

If this is not what you are looking for, then try using a proxy.

Comment: But how do I provide the values to be posted?  I don't want to use sendkeys to the fields as this is not 100% reliable.  I want to do something like:

Comment: r = requests.post("http://url.com/blah.aspx?Data=2",
 data={'AirportList': airport,
        'CarrierList': carrier,
        'Submit': 'Submit',
        "__EVENTTARGET": "",
        "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
        "__EVENTVALIDATION": eventvalidation,
        "__VIEWSTATE": viewstate
        })

Comment: interesting concept, I never had any need to use it myself. Anyway, some googleing shows it is possible, check [this link](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/). It is not exactly what you are asking, but using cookies is probably the right direction.